# How to prove that $3^{20}+4^{9}+6^{10}$ is composite?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How to prove that $3^{20}+4^{9}+6^{10}$ is composite? I tried to simplify it to a common exponent, I ended up with $9^{10} + \frac{4^{10}}{4} + 6^{10}$. Can anyone help?

Comment: Including the context of this problem will help us know what sort of answer you're looking for (for example, "make a computer compute and factor it" is a valid method, but you might be looking for something else). Hint: consider $(3^{10}+2^9)^2$.

Comment: Write it as $(3^{10})^2+(2^9)^2+2\cdot 3^{10}\cdot 2^9$ and compare with the formula $a^2+b^2+2ab=(a+b)^2$.

Answer (score 3):

You are on the right track!  Next step:

> You very sneakily write it as $(3^{10}+2^{9})^2$.